# Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax

Tags: mysql

Pues eso, sé que el fallo es de sintaxis pero no se ver muy bien donde está, y los correctores de `mysql` no ayudan mucho, así que me gustaría que alguien me dijera como corregirlo para futuros programas de BBDD.

Gracias de antemano.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS palindroma$$
CREATE FUNCTION palindroma (p VARCHAR(30))
    RETURN VARCHAR(30)
BEGIN
    DECLARE P0 VARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE P1 VARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE P2 VARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE P3 VARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE p4 INT(30);
/*La función ROUND () redondea un número a un número específico de lugares decimales.*/
IF ROUND(CHAR_LENGTH(p)%2,0) = 0 THEN
    SET i = ROUND(CHAR_LENGTH(p)/2,0);
    SET P4 = 0;
L: LOOP
    SET P4 = P4 + 1;
    IF P4 < I  THEN
    SET P1 = LEFT(p,P0);
    SET P2 = RIGHT(p,P0);
IF SUBSTRING(P1,P4,1) <> SUBSTRING(P2,P4-I,1)THEN
    SET i ='No es polindroma';
LEAVE L;
    END IF;
ELSE
    SET i ='Es polindroma';
        LEAVE L;
END IF;
RETURN(i);
END LOOP L;
 ELSE
        SET i = 'FALLO';
    END IF;
    RETURN(i);
END;$$
```

Comment: Cuál es el mensaje de error?

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near

Comment: Puedes tabular el código? Se hace difícil ver donde empiezan y acaban los if y el loop.

Comment: Creo que la clave está justo en la parte del error que no nos estás mostrando... _for the right syntax to use near_ después de esta parte, debe haber algo entre comillas simples, un paréntesis, una coma, o algo parecido **for the right syntax to use near ')'** _ esto por ejemplo_

Comment: Es que no me deja mostrarlo por que supera los caracteres esto es la parte rtestante :  'RETURN VARCHAR(30) BEGIN DECLARE P0 VARCHAR(30); DECLARE P1 VARCHAR(30); DECLARE' at line 2

Comment: El codigo no está bien tabulado por lo que es dificil ver el error. Por otra parte si quieres hacer una funcion que devuelva si una palabra que reciba como parametro es palindroma o no simplemente haz esto --> RETURN(REVERSE(palabraParametro) = palabraParametro);